# ObjectQuery invalid argument

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, objectquery

i am having a hard time filtering data from a db_Entities model. I have a table bound to a comboBox1 and i am trying to filter data using the commitChanged event within the comboBox1 control. i am getting 2 errors. 1 is :The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery.ObjectQuery(string, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext)' has some invalid arguments.
the 2nd one is: cannot convert from 'SmallStore.db_Entities' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext'. i left the directory out to save space. here is the code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Query;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;


    namespace SmallStore
    {
         public partial class ViewProducts : Form
         {                
           private db_Entities db = new db_Entities();

    public ViewProducts()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Products.ToList();

        dataGridView1.Columns["ProductType"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["TransactionItems"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["Product_Type"].Visible = false;

        comboBox1.DataSource = db.Product_Type.ToList();
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Description";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Product_Type";

    }

    private void changeCommit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* filter products */
        ObjectQuery<Product> filteredProducts = new ObjectQuery<Product>("SELECT VALUE item FROM Products AS item WHERE item.ProductType = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue, db);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var querystring = "SELECT VALUE item FROM Products AS item WHERE item.ProductType = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue;  

Debugger.Break();  //Ensure querystring is what you want here

 var products = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(querystring).ToList();
```

Comment: Gonna give it a shot. Gonna read up and try to understand why the other code didn't work.

Comment: The code did not work. Im gonna repost the question to be more clear